# Does rehashing a randomly salted password at login increase security?

Tags: php, security, hash, salt

I am currently working on a project in PHP, and am wondering how to make my system as secure as currently possible. I am currently using `password_hash` to hash my passwords and then store them in my database. What I was wondering: Does rehashing and re-saving the new salted hash to the database increase security, or is that just an illusion?

Comment: Yes, it does. Why? Look for example here: https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, I will definitely implement it then!

Comment: @syck: what part of that article are you referring people to?

Comment: @syck: I didn't get the same conclusion from this article as you did. What it does say is, that you should not use the same salt value every time. You must use a new random salt each time a password changes. However, nowhere is stated that it's a good idea to change the salt even if the password stays the same.

Comment: I should have added that ideally the salt should be dynamically created from user data for each entry. That would prevent saving same passwords with the same hash value and force the attacker to put in a considerable amount of reverse engineering to get any results. Of course, its still "security through obscurity".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think it will increase security, no. You have two risk scenarios:

- The cracker breaks into a server and stays there for some time undetected. In this case, passwords can just be captured programmatically, as users log in. This requires much less effort than brute-forcing strong hash algorithms.
- The cracker breaks in, steals a copy of the database, and in response the sysadmin plugs the security hole and restores the server from backup quickly.

In the second case, the cracker has a set of usernames, email addresses and hashed passwords, which they may wish to try brute-forcing. There is no advantage to be had if these hashes were created once or a thousand times.

It's worth remembering what we're trying to guard against here. If the security of a website has been breached, there is a knock-on effect for users who have used the same username/password combination at other popular services. A major reason for hashing, and the purpose an attacker has in brute-forcing passwords, is to see if the users can be hacked elsewhere (for example their social media or bank accounts).

This is why we recommend that people should not re-use passwords, and instead that they should use strong passwords stored in a password manager. It is even better if people can use a different username and/or a different email per service. Incidentally, it is surprisingly easy to use an email per service: if you are on GMail with an address of `gmail.alias@gmail.com`, just do this:

```
gmail.alias+randomcode@gmail.com
```

The email should of course be stored in your password manager - if you forget this, you will not be able to use password reminder features, and you will be locked out unless the service is willing to accept some other proof of identity. Despite that, this approach is stronger against the ripple effect of using a service that is breached - a weak password reminder system elsewhere is harder to exploit if users always use different email addresses.

Users with their own domain name can do something similar - set up an email account to "catch all" and then use whatever aliases you like.

Comment: not to mention they can send out fake password reset emails where people click on a malicious link.

Comment: I always think of the easiest solution, and really, the easiest solution is to just ask people their passwords. 37% of the people will just give their passwords over the phone if you pretend to be working for a company they are customers of. And in your scenario you know the website, the branding and the automatic email format the company sends out... so lets make it easy on the customers, register a similar reading domain of spoof it, send customers there in the same enviroment, and reroute them to the original site with login post data. so simple really...

Answer (score 2):

Calculating a new hash with a new salt each time the user logs in, will **not** improve security of your system.

Since the password will be the same and only the salt changes, a cracker with access to the hashes can brute-force with exactly the same cost. Changing the salt will not improve the security, a salt is not a secret, it fullfills its job even if it is known. Hiding or changing it does not add any value (hiding is difficult and there are better methods to add a secret than to hide the salt).

Answer (score 2):

*First of all, i'm not a cryptography expert. I had a cryptography class at university, but that doesn't make me an expert.*

The reason for salt is so that dictionary attack against the hash won't work. Since the same password can be combined with many different salts, there are many different hashes possible. It is thus not possible to have a simple hash to password table, as would be possible without a salt.

Thus, there is no additional gain to be had from rehashing a password with a different salt. The new salt should be just as random as the old salt, and therefore just as secure.

However, when a password is not changed for a long time, it may be hashed using a hashing algorithm that was good at the time of hashing, but poor now. [PHP has built-in functions especially for password hashing since PHP 5.5](https://php.net/manual/en/ref.password.php).

The recommended way of operation is explained on the PHP website, but it boils down to this: Use `password_verify` to check a password, use `password_hash` to encrypt a password. Use `password_needs_rehash` to check if a password is hashed using a secure hash. If it is not, either rehash it, or ask the user to change it (depending on your security policy).